# Cannot set cancellable for subscription in SwiftUI View

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have a mock network service that gives a publisher and I don't know how to handle the cancellable in a SwiftUI View. I get the following when I try to store the cancellable into my Set of AnyCancellable,

"Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'self' is immutable"

The view is a value type and thus cannot be mutated here. But I don't know what to do, to get around this.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport
import Combine
import Foundation
import Network

struct Node: Identifiable {
    var id: String
}

class NetworkService {
    func startScan() -> AnyPublisher<[Node], Never> {
        return Just<[Node]>([Node(id: "mike")])
            .delay(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue(label: "test"))
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func stopScan() {

    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var nodes = [Node]()

    var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    var service = NetworkService()

    var body: some View {
        List() {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            Button("Start") {
                service.startScan()
                    .assign(to: \.nodes, on: self)
                    .store(in: &self.cancellables) // Compiler Error: Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'self' is immutable
// I don't know the proper way to handle the cancellable in a SwiftUI View.
            }
            Button("Stop") {
                service.stopScan()
                nodes.removeAll()
            }
        }
        List(nodes, id: \.id) { node in
            Text("node: \(node.id)")
        }
        .onReceive($nodes.publisher.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)) {
            print("recieve data: \($0)")
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

The best thing I can think of is adding this

```
fileprivate class CancellableSetWrapper {
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
}

// and then change to store into a property like this
.store(in: &self.wrapper.cancellables)
```

Is this the proper way or is there something better out there?

Does my wrapper object need the @StateObject property wrapper?

Comment: Your cancellable set can be `@State`

Comment: Worth learning value types before starting SwiftUI. FYI when using Combine in SwiftUI you can use ObservableObject and `@Published` with `.assign` there is no need to use cancellables at all.

Comment: @malhal The cancellable set I defined messes up the mutability of the View, which is a no-no. How does using the State property wrapper bypass this? We changed the code from manipulating a value type of Set, to manipulating a value type of State. What makes State special?

Comment: State is separate storage associated with this View's position in the hierarchy (called its identity). If the View struct is re-init in the same position in the hierarchy it is given the same state value as last time. Essentially it makes the immutable struct like a mutable object.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to modify the property directly. Thats why you are getting the error "Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'self' is immutable" Instead you can try to create Binding to the Nodes property and update it via binding

You can try to modify the button

```
Button("Start") {
service.startScan()
    .sink { nodes in
        self.nodes = nodes
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

}

remove the .onRecieve modifier because .sink will also take care of that. In the end it should look like this

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var nodes = [Node]()

    var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    var service = NetworkService()

    var body: some View {
        List() {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            Button("Start") {
                service.startScan()
                    .sink { nodes in
                        self.nodes = nodes
                    }
                    .store(in: &cancellables)
            }
            Button("Stop") {
                service.stopScan()
                nodes.removeAll()
            }
        }
        List(nodes, id: \.id) { node in
            Text("node: \(node.id)")
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Comment: Same error on the store(in: &cancellable)

Comment: could you try changing it to ".store(in: &self.cancellables)" (self.cancellables instead of cancellables)